# Can you have a generic primary constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

This would work:

```
class Generic<T, R>(thingy: R)
{
    val x = thingy.getX()
}
```

But the parameter `R` should really not be a part of the class signature. It is relevant only at construction time. The same way a type parameter of a generic method has nothing to do with the type parameters of the class.

However, this does not work:

```
class Generic<T>(thingy: R)
{
    val x = thingy.getX()
}
```

neither does this:

```
class Generic<T><R>(thingy: R)
{
    val x = thingy.getX()
}
```

and I did not find the answer in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: To call `getX()` on a generic `R` type, it would have to implement some interface. A generic type with no bound will not have a `getX` method. You could just have the parameter to `Generic` be of that interface type directly: `class Generic<T>(thingy: RInterface) { ... }`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not possible directly.

You can however achieve a desired result by using a factory method:

```
interface HasX<out V> {
    val x: V
}

class Generic<T>(val x: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun <T, R : HasX<Int>> create(thingy: R) = Generic<T>(thingy.x)
    }
}

val result: Generic<String> = Generic.create(object : HasX<Int> {
    override val x: Int = 12
})
```

Typically factory methods start with lower case ( e.g. `mutableList`) there is nothing stopping you from doing it differently:

```
fun <T, X : HasX<Int>> Generic(thingy: X):Generic<T> = Generic(thingy.x)

val result: Generic<String> = Generic(object : HasX<Int> {
    override val x: Int = 12
})
```

As noted by [@Alexey Romanow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov) parts of the Kotlin stdlib use [this approach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions).

Comment: You can also use `operator invoke`.

Comment: And the standard library also has `public inline fun <T> MutableList(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): MutableList<T>`.

Comment: "That is not possible directly." Kotlin sucks